# Simple question on discrete random variable. 6 balls a drawn from a bag of balls numbered 1 to 49 with replacement.

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics

**Question:**

6 balls are drawn from a bag of balls numbered 1 to 49 with replacement.

The uniform distribution is being used.

What is the $F_X(k)$? That is, what is the cumulative distribution function evaluated at k?

**Where I am at so far:**

The set of outcomes in my sample space Ω is $49^6$ six-tuples, ($w_1, w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5,w_6$) where $w_i$ is the ith pick and $w_i$ ∈ {1,2,3,...,49}

X : Ω --> R defined by X( ($w_1, w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5,w_6$) ) = max{$w_1, w_2,w_3,w_4,w_5,w_6$} is our discrete random variable.

Image set of X = $S_X$ = (1, 2, 3, ..., 49}

I understand that the number of tuples whose max number drawn is $k^6$.

I know $F_X(k)$ = P(X ≤ k) = $\sum_{x = 1}^{k} p_X(x) = p_X(1) + p_X(2) +... + p_X(k)$.

But I still I can't see why $F_X(k)$ = P(X ≤ k) = $\frac{k^6}{49^6}$ because isn't P( X = k ) = $p_X(k)$ = $\frac{k^6}{49^6}$

$p_X(x)$ is the probability mass function.

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1,\dots 6$ let $X_i$ denote the number of the $i$-th ball that is drawn.

Then: $$\{X\leq k\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^6\{X_i\leq k\}$$ or in words $X\leq k$ if and only if $X_i\leq k$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5,6$.

This $6$ events are independent so we find:$$P(X\leq k)=P(X_1\leq k,\dots,X_6\leq k)=\prod_{i=1}^nP(X_i\leq k)=\left(\frac{k}{49}\right)^6$$Here: $$P(X=k)=P(X\leq k)-P(X\leq k-1)=\left(\frac{k}{49}\right)^6-\left(\frac{k-1}{49}\right)^6$$

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Statistics is my most difficult subject and so I'm having a hard time reading you're answer. Could you please explain each step.

Comment: If $m=\max(a,b)$ then do you agree that e.g. $m\leq3$ if and only if $a\leq3$ and $b\leq 3$? In that sense we have $X\leq k$ if and only if $X_1\leq k$ and $X_2\leq k$ and $\cdots$ and $X_6\leq k$. The probability of the event on right hand side can be found by multiplication because the six events are independent.

Comment: Why are the 6 events independent?

Comment: Because the balls are replaced. That means that $6$ times we have **exactly the same situation** (a number is drawn out of $1,2,\dots,49$) and the result for some specific draw (e.g. the first, or e.g. the last) is in no way dependent from the other results. Things would be different if the balls were not replaced. Then there is dependence.